# When Exporting file to pdf via VBA, range seems to be unrecognized

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to get this one to run, but without success due to an error 1004 (Application or Object Definition related) and I can't find the root cause for this, since the line the debbugger points to seems correct.

Below is the piece shown as where the error is:

```
'ActiveSheet.Range("A1:K" & lastrow).Select
       'Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=File, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
```

Below goes the entire code:

```
Sub SendGmailPDF()

    Dim File        As String
    Dim Folder      As Variant
    Dim cdoNS       As String
    Dim cdoMsg      As Object
    Dim htmlMsg     As String
    Dim Password    As String
    Dim strBCC      As String
    Dim strCC       As String
    Dim strMsg      As String
    Dim strSubj     As String
    Dim strTo       As String
    Dim UserEmail   As String
    Dim RelatorioComissao As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowResults As Range
    Dim lastrow     As Long
    Dim Data        As Date
    Dim List        As String
    Dim Rng         As Range

    Set RelatorioComissao = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Relatório de Comissão")
    Data = RelatorioComissao.Range("B8").Value

       ' Email Information.
        strTo = RelatorioComissao.Range("B6").Value
        strSubj = "Relatório de Comissão" & "-" & RelatorioComissao.Range("B5").Value & "-" & Format(Data, "mmm/yy")
        strMsg = "Em anexo, segue o relatório de comissão. Sugerimos que revisem os detalhes."
        strCC = ""
        strBCC = ""
        ReplyTo = ""
        ' Gmail Account Information.
        UserEmail = RelatorioComissao.Range("B3").Value
        Password = RelatorioComissao.Range("B4").Value


        If UserEmail = "" Or Password = "" Then
            MsgBox "Informe seu email e senha!"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        File = "Relatório de Comissão" & RelatorioComissao.Range("B5").Value & "-" & Format(Data, "mmm/yy") & ".pdf"
            If RelatorioComissao.Range("A17").Value = "" Then
                lastrow = 16
                MsgBox "Não há comissão no período!"
                Exit Sub
            Else
                'lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

                lastrow = Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row
                'lastrow = RelatorioComissao.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            End If


       RelatorioComissao.Range("A1:K" & lastrow).ExportAsFixedFormat _
       Type:=xlTypePDF, _
       Filename:=File, _
       Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
       IgnorePrintAreas:=False

       'ActiveSheet.Range("A1:K" & lastrow).Select
       'Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=File, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IgnorePrintAreas:=False



       cdoNS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"


           Set cdoMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")


            With cdoMsg
                .To = strTo
                .Subject = strSubj
                .From = UserEmail
                .ReplyTo = ReplyTo
                .CC = strCC
                .BCC = strBCC
                .TextBody = strMsg
                .AddAttachment File

                 With .Configuration.Fields
                    .Item(cdoNS & "smtpusessl") = True              ' Any non zero value is True
                    .Item(cdoNS & "smtpauthenticate") = 1           ' basic clear text
                    .Item(cdoNS & "sendusername") = UserEmail
                    .Item(cdoNS & "sendpassword") = Password
                    .Item(cdoNS & "smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
                    .Item(cdoNS & "sendusing") = 2                  ' Using Port
                    .Item(cdoNS & "smtpserverport") = 465           ' Gmail SMTP Port
                    .Item(cdoNS & "smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
                    .Update
                End With

                .Send
            End With
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: `Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row` - you want `xlUp` instead of `xlDown`. And where do you assign `File` a value?

Comment: It think File is assingned value at `File = "Relatório de Comissão" & RelatorioComissao.Range("B5").Value & "-" & Format(Data, "mmm/yy") & ".pdf"`  @BigBen

Comment: I think your `lastrow = Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row` row is missing Worksheet asignment on the Range, this way it is referenced to `ActiveWorksheet`, it should be: `lastrow = RelatorioComissao.Cells(RelatorioComissao.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`  I would never leave `Range` and `Cells` without explicitly referencing them to a  Worksheet. And of course the Worksheet would have to be explicitly referenced to a Workbook object to avoid errors like this. I would probably use AcviveWorkbook for Workbook assignment exacly as you did (when I am only working with one Workbook)

Comment: Then there is no room for ambiguity in what a Range or a Cells statement will link to. This way there is a very obvious chain of Objects.

Comment: Are you using Range in exporting to PDF because you don't want to export the whole Worksheet?

Comment: Is your code fixed by @BigBen 's suggestion? If it is could you make it obvious by a comment, please, instead of just leave it hanging...

Comment: @AndrasDorko missed the `File=...` line, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @AndrasDorko , thanks for helping me out with this one. It is still presenting the error and it keeps saying that this is on
```
RelatorioComissao.Range("A1:K" & lastrow).ExportAsFixedFormat _
       Type:=xlTypePDF, _
       Filename:=File, _
       Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
       IgnorePrintAreas:=False ```

I've tried @BigBen 's suggestion, but the error persists.

Comment: What does the error message say exactly on that line?

Comment: @AndrasDorko: Timeout error: 1004
Application or Object Definition Error. If I debug, it points to the piece of code.

Comment: @Antonio Santos --- Is there a ForwardSlash "/" in the content of your variable called File? because of the date... If there is then you are having problems because of it... I believe because ForwardSlash is probably an illegal character in filenames...

Comment: Yepp, "/" is a reserved character. Filenames cannot contain a [list of characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words). You could replace the "/" in the content of your variable File like `Replace(File, "/", "_")` once the File variable is assigned and before exporting to PDF, or early on when you format your Date you could immediately use "_" instead of "/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, as in my comments above, if you change:

```
 File = "Relatório de Comissão" & RelatorioComissao.Range("B5").Value & "-" & Format(Data, "mmm/yy") & ".pdf"
```

to:

```
 File = "Relatório de Comissão" & RelatorioComissao.Range("B5").Value & "-" & Format(Data, "mmm_yy") & ".pdf"
```

It should work...

At the end of the content of variable File this: `/` has been replaced to that: 
`_`

Or certainly you could choose your own Date Separator Character, just make sure it is none of the [Reserved Characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words)...

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've fixed it:

```
    If RelComissao.Range("A17").Value = "" Then
        lastrow = 16
        MsgBox "Não há comissão no período!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        lastrow = Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End If

    With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        Folder = .Namespace(0).Self.Path & "\"
        File = Folder & ActiveWorkbook.Name
        File = File & RelComissao.Range("B5").Value & "-" & Format(Data, "mmm-yy") & ".pdf"
        RelComissao.Range("A1:K" & lastrow).Select
        Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=File
    End With
```

I think that because I hadn't specified a place where the file should be exported to, AddAttachment couldn't catch it and the code got stuck there.
Also, I changed the way lastrow consisted of.
I'm sorry, I'm not a developer and can't go any deeper (concept wise) why this solution worked. 
By the way, the original code was obtained from VBA Express - by Leith Ross.

Thank you all who helped me get through this. It was driving me crazy!

Comment: When you have no Folder Path specified, then your Document folder is where the .PDF is created... So no that is not what the problem was...

Comment: Well, yes you have changed your code, what makes this new code work is exactly what I suggested above... You swapped your Date separator character to "-" instead of "/". If you change that character in you new code block back to "/", then your code is going to fail exactly as your first code block did. With exactly the same error message. So forgive me for not being able to accept that you solved your problem...

Comment: If you are really curious then you'll try what I just suggested, and you'll see that my solution is what makes your new code work...

Comment: I guess you haven't seen my answer above yours, and posted before yours...?

Comment: DId you not get emails about the Comments I left on your Original Post with the solution?

Comment: Hi @AndrasDorko, I'm not getting email alerts for comments. I'll mark your suggestion as the solution.

Comment: Thanks, you don't have to accept my answer, but did you check if your new code fails if you change Date Format like in your old code?

Comment: If I were you, I would want to know exactly what has fixed it, don't just accept someone's opinion (mine in this case)...

Comment: @AndrasDorko, You are correct! I did try adjusting the date format and I guess I got lost with the other corrections/changes underway. I just tested it and it breaks when using "/" instead if "-" or "_". thank you for the energy you've put into helping me. Busy Sun learning for me!

Comment: Great news.. Exactly as you said this is all why it is worth doing it.. Learning forever... Thank you, I am glad to help... It is a learning curve for mee too..